# Why does Node.js exist circular dependency among modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found Node.js exist circular dependency among modules,e.g.,
"es5-ext" depends the module "es6-symbol",

```
"dependencies": {
    "es6-iterator": "~0.1.3",
    "es6-symbol": "~2.0.1"
},
```

However, "es6-symbol" also depends the module "es5-ext", as follows,

```
"dependencies": {
    "d": "~0.1.1",
    "es5-ext": "~0.10.5"
},
```

"Circular dependency can cause many unwanted effects in software programs"(from Wikipedia "Circular dependency").So why does Node.js exist circular dependency among modules?

Comment: "*Circular dependency can cause many unwanted effects in software programs*" - can you cite evidence for that claim? I don't see what's wrong here.

Comment: All it is meaning to have circular dependency in node is that both need to be present in order to work. It may not be best practice but as long as it doesn't break anything in node js i don't see a problem there.

Comment: well.. we are still traumatize from C++ days when a circular declaration during inheritance would ended-up in a dead-lock

Comment: @Binvention just for clarity: circular dependency in Node.js is permitted?

Comment: Sorry autocorrect can be weird sometimes

Comment: Circular dependencies are permitted, but may cause unexpected behaviour https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles